# How to use address ranges in shorewall rules?

Tags: centos, firewall, iptables, shorewall

I want to add rule for a range of IP addresses from `64.240.160.0 to 64.240.191.255`.

Comment: For what purpose?  What port/protocol, what are they trying to access.  What are you trying to do that isn't covered in the shorewall docs?

Comment: @Zoredache lets make it simple, say you own a site, you installed shorewall, but you want to give ssh access to the ip of your friend, [you can do that](http://learninginlinux.wordpress.com/2008/05/07/shorewall-accepting-ssh-access-from-certain-ip-addresses-only/) but what you do if he has many ips, how to accept `64.240.xxx.x` to `64.240.xxx.x ` you can't add them manually, coz there are too many, i hope you understand the question better now

Comment: @Zoredache it's basically how to accept ssh access from certain ips if they are too many, can u specify an interval?

Comment: Ah, you are just asking how to use ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `shorewall show capabilities` and see if your kernel was compiled with the [iprange support](http://www.shorewall.net/configuration_file_basics.htm#IPRanges).

If it doesn't have that kind of support, then just enter your rules as a CIDR style network definition.  So `64.240.160.0/23` == `64.240.160.0 to 64.240.191.255`.